# how to install kernel module for blk_mq's io schedulers?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, io, kernel-module

I have recently changed single queue to multi queue on my oracle server. This server is oracle linux 6.10 (4.1.12 kernel). I realize there is no any io scheduler for blk_mq alse show the /sys/block//queue/scheduler is none. I think I have to install kernel module for io scheduler but I don't know how can I do that. How can I enable mq_deadline or bfq io scheduler for multi queue IO block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These modules do not exist in the v4.1 kernel (neither in mainline nor Oracle UEK).

`mq_deadline` was added in [v4.11](https://git.kernel.org/linus/945ffb60c11dfb228130f3f2bdde961cecb76671) and `bfq` first appeared in [v4.12](https://git.kernel.org/linus/aee69d78dec0ffdf82e35d57c626e80dddc314d5).